# Why is there a ROOT (as opposed to root) account for MySQL and MariaDB?

Tags: root, mysql, non-root-user, database, mariadb

As far as I can tell, the MySQL and MariaDB database "ROOT" account is completely separate from the operating system's "root" account.  Why did someone consider it a good idea to create the ambiguous name?  Am I correct that they are different entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating systems don't identify entities such as users, groups, etc by name. They identify them by what's usually a numeric or alphanumeric identity known as the UID in Unix-like operating systems or the SID in Windows that's pulled from `/etc/passwd` or an LDAP database (or whatever method is being used for authentication).

`root` or the super user for the OS is completely different for the `root` for MySQL or MariaDB. The second one only exists for MySQL or MariaDB and can only be identified that way. It's no different than if you have a local or LDAP user called `cygni` and a MySQL user called `cygni`. The OS isn't even aware of the second one because it only exists for the RDBMS where there is a database and table containing the user information. While I don't recommend trying this, you can give a local or LDAP user read access to the data directory for MySQL but you won't be able to log into the MySQL instance with that user or do anything in the databases if it doesn't exist in the instance or have permissions to do so. While some RDBMSs can be set up to authenticate via LDAP or the system's auth, it still would be able to do anything as it wouldn't have direct access and would have no idea of the password, etc. With that being said, you are correct in that they are two different entities.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Nasir.  As an old Unix admin, I consider this a really bad decision on the part of the database writers.  The root (uid 0) account should be treated as off-limits by the database.  It would have been much better to call the database admin account DBA, Admin, or Bob -- anything but ROOT! Now that I know, I know!  And thank you!

Comment: @ChrisKnox You are welcome. The concern is understandable but as the name isn't how it's identified, it's harmless because the RDBMS doesn't have any idea of the auth method for the system and the environment that it's running in is totally different from the system.

Comment: You're correct of course.  There are RDBMS's (e.g. Informix) that use the OS authentication as a service.  I was not familiar enough with the administration of MySQL to be certain.  I ran a query to look at the user (SELECT host,user,password FROM mysql.user;) and saw that the hash of the ROOT password was the same as a user I knew the password for.  Question answered.  I am still curious why someone would think it a good idea, but it's moot. 

Cheers and stay well!

Comment: @ChrisKnox I added a note about RDBMSs that can authenticate via LDAP or system auth. Take care and you do the same.